# A few spring junit tests doesn't rollback. Because of out of memory errors?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, oracle11g, junit4

I have more than 5000 Spring unit tests and I know every test works against Oracle DB and does a rollback as I have tested every single one individually. When I ran a maven test suite, I ended up with out of memory errors and found out that a few tests didn't rollback. I fixed the out of memory errors by adding a argLine param in my pom.xml and it doesn't happen anymore. But I am still trying to figure out if out of memory errors caused the rollback to fail? Or could it be something else? If out of memory is the culprit, what would be the best approach to handle/solve this problem in the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Does out of memory errors cause the rollback to fail? Or could it be something else?

The jvm cannot execute anything after it experiences an OutOfMemory Error. Since spring started the database transaction, it is supposed to be one who needs to call `transaction.rollback()`. Because your maven test suite experiences a OutOfMemory Error, rollback is never called and that should be the root cause.

> If out of memory is the culprit, what would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Increasing the jvm heap size could help out.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

E.g.

```
java -Xmx256m TestData.java
```

[This](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) might be the way how you could do in maven.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry I should have been more clear while posting the question. I already fixed the out of memory issue by adding a argLine param for maven surefire plugin in my pom.xml. Now out of memory doesn't happen. I was trying to ask how to address a problem when someone else runs the tests and end up with out of memory errors on their machine and cause the tests not to rollback. Any suggestions? I am editing my original question now. Please check.